# Server models and client objects in React / Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, functional-programming, redux

It is common in web applications to have server model objects, especially when using an ORM. These are usually just collections of some state and behavior.

In the past when I've developed iOS and web applications we'd usually have client side objects that, to some degree, mirror the server side objects. We would use a library like [Mantle](https://github.com/Mantle/Mantle) to parse JSON responses from the API into objects. A convenience of doing this is that you can preserve object relationships that are returned from the API. So, a `User` could have a property `var comments: [Comment]` where `Comment` is itself an API object.

I'm now working on a ReactJS / Redux project. In this world, we tend to have actions that get dispatched to update the application state. For example, a method like,

```
export const loadProfile = (cb) => {
  return async (dispatch, state) => {
    dispatch({ type: LOAD_SESSION_REQUEST })

    await api.getSelfProfile()
      .then((response) => {
        dispatch({
          type: LOAD_SESSION_SUCCESS,
          payload: { profile: response.data.message },
        })
      })
      .catch(() => {
        dispatch({ type: LOAD_SESSION_FAIL })
      })
    cb()
  }
}
```

loads the user profile.

I have a case where I'd like to create a property / getter which reads two fields from the user profile and returns a composite result (i.e. say the user has a city and state property and I want to return "*city, state*"). In the old world I'd just create a method on my client side `User` object that performs the logic.

I'm wondering how to accomplish this using React / Redux. I know React encourages a more functional approach which separates state from behavior.

So should I use base Javascript Objects for my API data and then some utility methods for all the extra functionality I need (i.e. have some `userCityState(user)` which returns "*city, state*") ?  Or should I use client side objects a la Mantle? If so, is it possible to have typed `User` objects on the client?

Comment: i think you are talking about `Selectors`

Comment: https://github.com/reactjs/reselect